# Does anybody know any pure UIKit game source?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uikit

I know there are the cocos2d-iphone and Sparrow frameworks out there, but my current game is pretty simple. Does anybody know any links to the source of a simple game or app alike built purely on UIkit? Currently I'm struggling to design a simple and standard game architecture with main menu class + xib (built with interface builder), game content class and some uitableview for displaying top 10 scores. The game also will have basic functionality such as start, pause the game, load, save the game state. I know how to build separate components but I'm not sure how to combine them in a clean model that consists for clean MVC's :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one for normal Cocoa (`NSView`, etc.):

http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/02/asteroids-style-game-in-coreanimation.html

It claims to be Core Animation based, so most of it should translate well to iOS, and all the concepts/design patterns will certainly be very similar.

Comment: Thanks. However, I'm struggling to have an insight how should the game architecture would look like with a separate menu MVC. All the game samples that I saw are just snippets. I have also posted a relevant question on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6478160/how-should-correctly-look-the-simple-game-architecture